# How Do I Destroy A DirectShow Category After Creating It?

Tags: directshow

MSDN is refreshingly straightforward about using [IFilterMapper2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390034(v=vs.85).aspx) to create a category for the registration of DirectShow filters:

```cpp
IFilterMapper2 *pFM2 = NULL;

CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterMapper2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IFilterMapper2, (void **)&pFM2);

pFM2->CreateCategory(
    CLSID_MyFiltersCategory,         // Category.
    MERIT_DO_NOT_USE,                // Merit.
    L"My Filters"                    // Description.
);

pFM2->Release();
```

However, there is no "DestroyCategory" method defined for the interface. I would rather not perform any sort of archeological dig on the registry. Does anyone know a reliable way to destroy a DirectShow category after having created it with IFilterMapper2::CreateCategory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do the archeology - there is no method to delete a category. The good thing is that it is pretty simple:

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<category-GUID>`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{DA4E3DA0-D07D-11d0-BD50-00A0C911CE86}\Instance\<category-GUID>`

Comment: Thanks, Roman. I've spent the last three hours doing that archeology and was still trying to confirm I hadn't missed anything, but your answer matches my digging. Coming from you, I regard that as authoritative, so I'm marking your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Hey Roman! I recently happened on your blog post about PolyTextOut (http://alax.info/blog/1527) while Googling for the documentation. Your blog post had me concerned about using the function, so I tested it out. I can't reproduce your results. On a US English version of Windows 7 (also tested back on US English Win 2k), I get the correct output using PolyTextOut. So I'm curious what it is you were doing differently. Obviously you'd know to use a Unicode build of the app, and you have to be using a font that supports those characters, since it worked correctly for ExtTextOut.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that Visual Studio has a known tendency to mangle source files that are not saved in ASCII format. When I tested it, I used the Unicode escapes to encode the characters (e.g., `L"\x10D3\x10D4\x10D3\x10D0\x10E1"`). Anyway, I hope you'll pardon me abusing the SO comment system to reach out to you.I didn't really want to create an account on your blog... :-)

Comment: @CodyGray We can take it to email (and delete these unrelated comments) if you [email me](http://alax.info/blog/about). I have full code for this issue and its reproduction in SVN/Trac. Since then I upgraded dev system to 8.1 and then to 10. Re-built the code again and it still gives me the posted results.